# Quiero cambiar el tamaño de letra de todos mis textView en la app en Android Studio

Tags: java, xml

Quiero cambiar el tamaño de letra de todos mis `textView` en la app en Android Studio, tener tres botones que me den la posibilidad de tres tamaños grande, normal y pequeño

Comment: Hola, ¿a qué texto? ¿En qué textview? No es claro qué quieres hacer; por favor comparte el código relevante a tu pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda que es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.